# Get the sub string between two bracket in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have following strings:

```
1) Beach Cottage (CP)
2) Beach Cottage (AP)
3) Cotta (GAP)
```

And I want to get substing between `( )` that is from first `CP`

Comment: We expect you to show us what code you've written, or at least citing where you've searched and read when trying to solve the problem. Showing you've made an effort is important; we don't expect you to know how to do these things but we do want to see that you've tried. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for example:

```
str = "Beach Cottage (CP)"
str.match(/(\((.*)\))/)[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

**you can use scan also with regx:**

```
str = "Beach Cottage (CP)"    
needed_sub_str = str.scan(/\((.*)\)/)

puts "expected sub string :: #{needed_sub_str}"
```

**Output ::**

```
expected sub string :: CP
```